# Parsing text into javascript String

Tags: javascript, text-parsing

I am trying to parse some text into javascript strings. In essence I have a String in javascript containing what would be another javascript string. Here are some samples that I have in my tests:

```
input1: '"This \\"should\\" work"' 
output1: 'This "should" also work'

input2: '"Another working \\nstring\\n with newlines"'
output2: 'Another working \nstring\n with newlines'

// Should throw an exception since it would escape the last ":
input3: '"This should not work\\"'

// Should throw an exception since it contains an illegal newline
input4: '"This \n should also not work"'
```

I was considering using `eval` on the input strings but it feels like a hack and I am unsure if it is safe. <strike>It doesn't yield an error on the `input3` sample when I try it in Node.</strike>It works when running my tests but not when used I run: `eval('"This should not work\\"')` in Node directly.

**How can I parse the above sample inputs to their corresponding outputs and still get errors for the bad samples?**

**EDIT:**
My initial atempt:

```
output = input.slice(1, input.length - 1)
```

My second atempt:

```
output = eval(input);
```

Using `eval` seems to work , but feels like a hack.

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Comment: @Greg added a couple of my initial atempts. The eval solution seems to work in my tests, but it feels like a hack... is there a better way?

Comment: Why do double quotes in the input turn into single quotes in the output?

Comment: @Barmar I'm just showing the equivalent JS literal representation of the expected output string.

Comment: Why shall ``'"This should not work\\"'`` not work? Wouldn't it be the result ``"This should not work\"``?

Comment: @tampis And that result is not a valid JS literal string.

Comment: `toString()` works with `\n`... it also uses `\ ` to escape...I'm not sure what exactly your trying to get though.

Comment: @13ruce1337 How do you mean? Calling `toString()` on a `String` object just gives me an equivalent String it does not parse the escape sequences.